# How to convert BufferedImage to bytes correctly

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedimage

I use this code to convert it.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream simpan = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write((BufferedImage)image, "JPG", simpan);
```

But when I try to show the `simpan.toString`, the result was [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiIgs.png).

When I convert it to PNG like via

```
ImageIO.write((BufferedImage)image, "PNG", simpan);
```

I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uihf8.png).

Is this condition correct? And when I send those bytes to an android phone via socket, no image appeared on the phone.

Comment: What 'condition'?  You do realize the conversion to PNG/JPG will result in different byte[] for each, don't you?   BTW - Please copy/paste the output of your IDE rather than upload screenshots of it.

Comment: What do you mean in what condition @Andrew? Yes of course it will result different byte. I've tried to copy the result, but I got the differet character when I paste it, so I do upload the screenshot.:)

Comment: You asked *"Is this **condition** correct?"*  What do you mean by that?  It means nothing to me as it currently reads.

Comment: Oh I mean didn't it must be shown the RGB format, but why it only show a unknown character? Sorry when my question isn't well known.:)

Comment: If you dump bytes to the console or other typical 'text output' devices, the byte[] will contain values that do not map to any known character.  Try it with a valid PNG or JPG to convince yourself.  This is all unrelated to the fact that the phone does not show the image.

Comment: So I must convert that byte array to a file like jpg or .png first and send it from that file?

Comment: No, not at all.  I'm just saying that 'printing' the bytes of an image is in no way meaningful.  (Note that the 1st sentence of solendil's answer is wrong.)

Comment: So what should I do? Should I send that byte array to the phone or should I process that byte array first then send it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the content of the `ByteArrayOutputStream` to a file with the proper  extension, then open it with your file explorer. What you're doing right now is outputing the bytes of the JPEG or PNG images in a text console.

Comment: Isn't it got the same result when I show ByteArrayOutputstream directly via System.out.println()?

Comment: Absolutely NOT :) A print will output the bytes of the images, while opening a file with the proper extension in your OS will trigger the launch of a visualization program that knows how to turn these bytes into displayed pixels.

Comment: Okey, I'll try it as soon as possible @solendil. Thanks you've been try to answered my question. Wait for the result..Haha..:)

Comment: @ChristoforusSurjoputro, writing bytes out via `System.out.println` will not only add a newline at the end it will call `toString` on the `ByteArrayOutputStream` will convert the bytes to a String **using the default encoding** which is not what you want.  You need to use `.write(myByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray())` instead.

Comment: @solendil. I've tried it and I got well known character with fileinputstream. Did you mean I should send that well konown byte array to the phone?